# Understanding JDBC, ORM, JOOQ, Hibernate, spring data, JBDI

Tags: java, data-access, sql-server-2014-express

I have some experience in SQL Server(using 2014).
I just starting to learn Java and want to connect in my DB. I'll be loading table, performing queries, procs, functions, inserts/updates..etc...

So I Started to search and I find me a bit lost with all this names...
( JDBC, ORM, JOOQ, Hibernate, spring data, JBDI)

Need some clarification to understand it all and also a suggestion where to go.

Comment: JDBC is sufficient.  You don't need any of that other stuff.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

Comment: I concur with @duffymo. For starters, understand JDBC. Some time down the line, you might appreciate any of the additional libraries that you've listed (which all solve higher-level problems), but no matter which library you might eventually settle with, you'll still need to understand JDBC.